# Taking the converse of an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, logic

I'm trying to prove the statement

> $$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: 0 < 1 - x^\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$$

To do so, I'd the idea to take the converse of this statement, assume it's true and look for a contradiction.
However, I found the converse to be $\exists \epsilon > 0, \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: 0 \geq 1 - x^\frac{1}{N} \geq \epsilon$. This seems to immediately contradict that $\epsilon > 0$. Am I taking the converse of the statement incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to negate the formula : $0 < (1−x^{\frac 1 N}) < \epsilon$.

This is a shorthand for :

> $0 < (1−x^{\frac 1 N}) \text {  and   }  (1−x^{\frac 1 N}) < \epsilon$.

Thus, its negation will be :

> $\text {either  } 0 \ge (1−x^{\frac 1 N}) \text {  or  } (1−x^{\frac 1 N}) \ge \epsilon$.

Comment: I see. And if I wanted to show a contradiction, would it suffice to show that one of the above is impossible or would I have to show that both are impossible?

Comment: @carraig - You are working by contradiction and you have produced the negation of the statement to be proved. You want to show that the negated statement is FALSE (if so, the original statement will be TRUE). In order to show that a *disjunction* : "either P or Q" is FALSE, you have to show that both disjuncts : P and Q are FALSE.